# jquery plugin to make modal/popup enabled site

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Ruby on Rails and jQuery. Both most recent stable copy.

I need to make authentication and some other functionalities like updating the status of the delivered item though popup/modal. The form will have some complex validation logic etc.

I tried to use facebox but it hard to load javascript using facebox.

What jquery plugin should I be using.

Since I need access to javascript code do I must use iframe. Or are there better solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

It has the following description:

> SimpleModal is a lightweight jQuery Plugin which provides a powerful interface for modal dialog development. Think of it as a modal dialog framework. SimpleModal gives you the flexibility to build whatever you can envision, while shielding you from related cross-browser issues inherent with UI development.